# Keyboard not working in Grub, Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, keyboard

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my desktop which already had Windows 10. Unfortunately the keyboard(USB) is not working when it gets to the grub bootloader GUI where I can select the OS. Therefore,I am unable to use windows as Ubuntu is the default option in the menu. Can someone please help me to fix this? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a desktop, try a different USB port on your machine, some of them is bound to work. If not, check your BIOS to see to make sure you have Legacy USB enabled.